# <img> not showing when using a dynamic import from assets as source

Tags: nuxt.js, vite

This used to work with Nuxt2. What do I have to do to make it work with Nuxt3? The image does not show, but I get no error either.

```
<template>
    <button @click="doImportImage()">Import image</button>
    <template v-if="contactAvatarUrl">
        <img :src="contactAvatarUrl"
                width="100px"
                height="100px">
    </template>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
let contactAvatarUrl = ref();

const doImportImage = async () => {
    const contactAvatar = await import('~/assets/img/contact/1.jpg');
    contactAvatarUrl.value = contactAvatar.default
}
</script>
```

The image URL resolves to /_nuxt/assets/img/contact/1.jpg

I reread the [docs](https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/assets) carefully, and their example

```
<template>
  <img src="~/assets/img/nuxt.png" alt="Discover Nuxt 3" />
</template>
```

only works if

> a build tool is configured to handle this file extension

**What does it mean? How can I tell nuxt to handle PNG and JPG files?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this article answers it:

https://www.lichter.io/articles/nuxt3-vue3-dynamic-images/
https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/issues/14766/

For now, I will move my images to the public folder...